# sqlite encryption for android

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

i'm looking very hard for a possibility to encrypt my sqlite database on Android devices, but I was't able to find a satisfying solution.

I need something like a libary to reference, in order to have a "on the fly" encryption/decryption of my database, while using the normal sqlite functions.

I don't want to encrypt data before storing.

I don't want to encrypt the whole databasefile, in order to decrypt it before using.

I know about the following projects:

- [SEE](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html)
- [wxSQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxsqlite/)
- [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/)
- [SQLiteCrypt](http://sqlite-crypt.com/documentation.htm)
- [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/)

But I can't find any working example for this stuff.

Btw, I'm absolutly willing to purchase a commercial build, but I have to test ist before spending a few hundred dollars.

Did anyone solve this issue for his own?

Comment: There is no good reason to encrypt the database. If someone wants to access it he can always reverse engineer your application to retrieve the key.

Comment: no, not if i force the user so type the password while starting the app

Comment: Can't find any examples for SQLCipher? See https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try the [SQLCipher port to Android](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/) instead of the regular SQLCipher.

Comment: Using SQLCypher makes my app 8-10MB more bulky, after including the icudt46.zip file for solving compatibility problem. Any other light method to Encrypt the database?

Comment: @Saty: None that I am aware of.

Comment: How exactly do I download the binary, the Zetetic page leads to a download page with no actual download.

Comment: @Michael: Add `compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.3.1-2@aar'` to your `dependencies` in your module's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, hmm. Is it no longer possible to download a zip file and drop files somewhere in my project in Android Studio?

Comment: @Michael: If you are using Android Studio, you **really** should be using artifacts. If you do not want to rely upon a remote repository like JCenter or Maven Central, presumably you already have set up a local repository for things like the Android Plugin for Gradle (which come from remote repositories by default). If so, you can copy down the AAR and POM and add them to your own local repository, as you did with the Android Plugin for Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

[litereplica](http://litereplica.io) supports [encryption](http://litereplica.io/sqlite-encryption.html) using the ChaCha cipher, faster than AES on portable devices.

There are [bindings](http://litereplica.io/install-android.html) for Android.

To create and open an encrypted database we use an URI like this:

```
"file:/path/to/file.db?cipher=...&key=..."
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking:

Override `SQLiteOpenHelper` function as below:

```
void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA key = 'secretkey'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String encrypt(String password) {
   try {
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = generateKey(password);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(password.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(encVal,Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encryptedValue;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private SecretKeySpec generateKey(String password) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] bytes = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    digest.update(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    byte[] key = digest.digest();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
    return secretKeySpec;
}
```

I just used the `encrypt` function to encrypt the password. Here I used the user's password as a key. Therefore I don't need to keep the key inside the application. When the user wants to log in, simply encrypt the password and try to match with the encrypted password in the database and allow them to log in.