# How to make apk Secure. Protecting from Decompile

Tags: android, apk

I am developing an application that has SQLite database to store personal information that must be protected. What are some ways of protecting these personal data? An APK can easily be de-compiled completely, so how can we secure an APK? Additionally, how can a database of a mobile application be protected?

Comment: i want the same to secure my code base?

Comment: Check out my answer on a similar question:
[hiding strings in Obfuscated code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427238/hiding-strings-in-obfuscated-code/39856033#39856033)

Answer (score 8):

If this is secret information that must not fall into the hands of your users, you cannot secure it. It is fundamentally impossible to put information on a device (code or data), and have your application access it, but not allow someone with the device to have access to that information.

Encrypting the information is pointless from a security point of view, because your application has to contain whatever is needed to decrypt it in order to use it, and a sufficiently motivated attacker can always extract that and decrypt it on their own.

All you can do is make it more annoying and time consuming to get access to that information, which only helps if there's not really that much of a need to keep it secret. This is what using proguard to obfuscate your .apk file can do.

Comment: Sorry to Say but interestingly it make the code more easy to understand (proguard) :) i test it

Comment: I've rarely used proguard, and then only to strip out unnecessary parts of the Scala or Mercury standard library so programs written in Scala or Mercury were able to be translated for Android. But I believe it does have "obfuscate" options, that can mangle class/variable names and strip out other information potentially useful for reverse engineering. I would suspect you don't have them turned on if you found proguard output easier to read than the input source code.

Answer (score 8):

With Jellybean this has now become a possibility.

```
$ openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F 
-iv 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F -in my-app.apk -out my-app-enc.apk

$ adb install --algo 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding' --key 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F 
--iv 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F my-app-enc.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/my-app-enc.apk
Success
```

Please read the following blog post for further [details](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/using-app-encryption-in-jelly-bean.html)

Comment: I installed openssl-0.9.8 in my Windows machine and tried the above command with my apk. But its always saying `error in enc`. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered sqlite encryption? See this thread - [sqlite encryption for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043984/sqlite-encryption-for-android)

As for protecting your .apk, try obfuscating your code using proguard. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

Comment: Sorry to Say but interestingly it make the code more easy to understand (proguard) :) i test it

Comment: Same results.it seams proguard is for newbies ... for learning decoded code.

Answer (score 4):

You can try 'Anti Decompiler(Android)Trial'

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tth.AntilDecompilerTrial

It makes something Proguard doesn't:

- Hide all const values (string, character), you will never see clear text like "my key", "my val"... in your apk file
- Obfuscate file name, which is referenced in AndroidManifest.xml
- Add fake code to your source code. Event the powerful decompilers likes: dex2jar, jd-gui,... can't reverse exactly your apk file. Most of functions will show with comment 'Error'.

=====

- After transforming, if you give someone your source project, it will be nearly impossible to read and understand.
- This solution doesn't exclude Proguard, You can combine them together. (function, field Obfuscation of Proguard is better than Obfuscation features of this solution)

Answer (score 2):

If it is the database that contains sensitive data you can encrypt the values of several columns or the full database like mentioned in the other answer and make sure that the password is not stored on the device but has to be entered by the user on accessing the data.

If there are pieces of code you need to protect there's really no good way of securing it. All you can for a limited amount of use-cases is to create a dependency to an online service and secure the server. But for a lot of applications this would not be an option.

Answer (score 2):

You may read my post at: http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/forum/thread/567093/An-Analysis-of-Android-APK-Protect-Shell-APKProtect. The APK added with protect shell of APK Protect is seems unable decompile. I mean, the encrypt method is very advanced. Even a master hacker need long time to crack it.

Comment: APKProtect relies on bugs in the Android smali decompiler: it changes in the application so that the decompiler crashes and do not generate the source code. Thus, APKProtect will work until the decompiler targeted bug is corrected. See the comparison here: youtube.com/watch?v=t7M4AK1vZPA

Answer (score 0):

First, make apk that can never be modified and used. I do it by temper detection from the server. I use root check emulator check. Then on the important activity, it checks root and emulator on every oncreate and on resume, deletes important data on onpause, Great. Now encrypt data and place license to server, use SSL server. It app can not be modified and run, everything is safe for ever. Well, how to avoid decompiler and online tamper  detection. I do placing a huge code to generate some sample string from apk file, and compare it with an apk copy placed on the server. I have converted apk file to string. Just enjoy.