# How to hide properties file from compiled android apk

Tags: android, properties, apk

I have a security issue related to properties file. 
I have a project which when compiled and tested is working perfectly.

But when I view the contents of extracted apk file, I see a few properties files also lying in there.

For me this is a security problem. Any ideas how I might be able to hide/remove those properties files from the compiled apk.

Comment: What you mean by "properties files"?

Comment: @Minas - I mean .properties files.

Comment: may be this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235290/how-to-make-apk-secure-protecting-from-decompile

Comment: @prasadthangavel - No luck buddy. Besides from what I have read Progaurd is for java classes not for properties files.