# How to store sensitive data into java code for android development

Tags: java, android, email, security

I am willing to use java email api for my android app. I got it from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a). But as mentioned here in the link, to use this api, I need to give my own email id and password in **GmailSender** as ***Plain Text***. For this reason I am tensed about my password. If anyone decompile the apk file then he can easily get my email id and password. 
But I don't know how to store these sensitive data into my code safely. 
How can I do this?

**Note: I am not willing to use any third party library to encrypt thses data**

Comment: Why can't you use an SMTP server and send emails from an anonymous account?

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to completely protect your app from reversal engineering, especially without any third party library.

BUT instead you can create another e-mail, with a **different** password, and configure it to resend any email received to your official e-mail.

This way if anyone actually manage to reverse the code and get the password, they will only have access to this secondary and unimportant e-mail account. This should solve the problem.

More info about actually protecting the code here:

[How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)

[How to make apk Secure. Protecting from Decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235290/how-to-make-apk-secure-protecting-from-decompile)

Comment: Your idea is not bad. But I I have to use any library for protecting these data, then which is best and can you give me an example with that?

Comment: But none of them have any perfect answer. Everybody is suggesting. Nobody is answering

Comment: I wish i could help you more, But the thing is, it seems that this subject is not trivial. Truly protecting an app requires a lot of deep understanding of the matter, which i do not own.

Answer (score 0):

You should obfuscate your password string before keeping it in your source code. You can:

- Do it manually, It can be take a time.
- Or use some automatic tools. If you don't want to use any third party library to encrypt these data, [Bg+ Anti Decompiler/Obfuscator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bgplus.Anti.JavaDecompiler) is a good choice for you. *It works on java source code (not Java byte-code) so you will control everything*