# Android how to obfuscate static string constants?

Tags: android, string, android-proguard

```
String token="fbjfdjfdfjhhh";
```

my above string how to secure above string when my code revers engineering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235290/how-to-make-apk-secure-protecting-from-decompile

Comment: We can use "jni module" to keep 'Sensitive Hardcoded Strings' in-app when we try reverse engineer APK file we get lib folder and .so files in process-folders. which can not decrypt.