# Need to encrypt the DB file in android

Tags: android, database, encryption

Is there any way to encrypt the db file in android.I know its possible to encrypt the datas stored in db but what I want is to encrypt the whole db file of my application and should be possible to decrypt the db and take the datas from from db file .Is there any possible way to do it?Any help will be appriciable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043984/sqlite-encryption-for-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

Uses AES-256 bit encryption.Nice step by step Tutorial.

Comment: Is it possible to encrypt the whole database file?

Comment: Yes.The encryption is for the database file.