# How to encrypt SQlite database for android application?

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sqlite encryption for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043984/sqlite-encryption-for-android)

How i can encrypt sqlite database for my android application ?
My Application users sqlite database to store username and password of various online accounts.
please help me.

Comment: well hopefully for starters you are not storing the passwords as plain text?

Comment: where would the encryption key be stored? on disk? or in the form of a user password?

Comment: i am using encryption logic to encrypt password but i also wan to encrypt sqlite database to improve security can u help me with that??

Comment: i will get password form the edittext box and then apply some encryption logic and after that sotre in the local sqlite database.

Comment: but what about the encryption key used to encrypt the passwords and the whole database? where does it come from?

Comment: look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6043984/265597)

Comment: Thanks Lecho i got the solution of my problem thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

But be aware, that you need to use proguard to [obfuscate](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) your decryption code and password. Otherwise it would be an easy task to reverse engineer your application and decrypt the database.

The best solution would be if the user needs to enter the password to your database each time so you dont have to store it in your code where a reverse engineer can find it.